# I am unable to customize the style property with mat-grid-tile of angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying to create 6 tiles in each row and each tile consists of amount at the top left, + symbol at the top right, below Charity name, then below date at the extreme left and so on. But everything is coming in the middle. How to Customize the style for each mat-grid-tile.

```
HTML Example

mat-grid-list cols="6" rowHeight="4:3" [gutterSize]="'10px'">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index">
    <div class="div-table">
      <div class="div-row">
        <div class="div-cell" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium;">{{amount | currency}}</div>  
      </div>
      <div class="div-row">
        <div>{{item.Name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-grid-tile>

CSS Example


mat-grid-tile {
  background: lightblue;
}

.div-table {
  display: table;         
  width: auto;         
  background-color: #eee;         
}
.div-row {
  display: table-row;
  width: auto;
  clear: both;
}
.div-cell {
  float: left; 
  display: table-column;         
  width: 200px;         
  background-color: #ccc;  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma615395976433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgrid-list-overview-example.html).

You can put a `div` inside the tile to work as a container element (to avoid messing up with `mat-grid-tile` style). Inside this container, you can use `flex-box` to build your layout as you want. The container `div` of each tile could have something like:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then, inside the container `div`, you could have 3 `section` elements: **header** (taking 20%+ of the available vertical space), **footer** (taking 20%+ of the available vertical space), and **body** (taking whatever space wasn't taken by header and footer):

```css
.container > .header {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  order: 1; /* Assure this is the first element, at the top */
}

.container > .footer {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  order: 3; /* Assure this is the third element, at the bottom */
}

.container > .body {
  flex: 1;
  order: 2; /* Assure this is the second element, in the middle */
}
```

You can do almost anything you want from here. For example, you said you wanted to have, in the header, the name on the left and a symbol on the right. So let's turn the header also into another flex container itself, with two `section` elements: `header-start` and `header-end` (just in case you want different CSS styles for them):

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  order: 1;
}
```

The overall html would be like:

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4]">
        <div class="container">
            <section class="header">
                <section class="header-start>
                    Charity name
                </section>
                <section class="header-end">
                    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
                </section>
            </section>

            <section class="footer">
                footer
            </section>

            <section class="body">
                body
            </section>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Great solution. In my case, i was nesting flex-layout inside mat-grid-tile and was unable to set width=100% for content inside the tile(it was set to display: flex). I couldn't change mat-grid-tile styles from styles.scss because I had already added some !important properties to it. Your solution was just i was looking for after wasting 1 hour on this. Cheers